# Entity Framework, WebApi not allow post of table ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, model

I have this basic project that I'm using to learn ASP.NET and I'm using Entity Framework to talk to the database.

I have this simple [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plr6g.png), and when I make a post the API to create a new `equipa`, I don't want to let the user specify the id.

I've read the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) and I've tried using the data annotation

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

on my [model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0wrc.png), but it still allows the user to define the `equipa` id in the ([API Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6dLl.png)).

How do I make that the user isn't allowed to define the id and let PostgreSQL generate the id itself?

[My controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb0Og.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the database table set the id column as identity: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/

Also define your property in the model with only { get; }

Comment: it worked, but i had to add  `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Equipas>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.equipaid });
        }` to my database context in this case *BasicApiContext*, for some reason the keyword `[Key]` in the model wasn't enough. ty